# Timeseries forecasting - Two values for slope

Tags: time-series, octave

I am trying to do the classic method of decomposition of time series. I have somehow managed to get myself to the very last step where I'm supposed to calculate the Trend from the Trend-Cycle series using slope and intercept but I get 2 values instead of one for some reason. Why does `slope` contain two values?

```
pkg load io;
pkg load financial;
data = xlsread('exerciseinfo.xlsx','Φύλλο1','A1:B60');
 
t = data(:,1);
Y = data(:,2);

#Γραφική Παράσταση Δεδομένων
plot(t,Y);

title('Αφίξεις Αυτοκινήτων ανά Μήνα');
xlabel('Μήνας');
ylabel('Αφίξεις');

average = mean(Y);

#ΚΜΟ (5)
M = movmean(Y,5);

plot(t,M);
title('KMO(5)');
xlabel('Μήνας');
ylabel('Αφίξεις');

#Διπλός ΚΜΟ 3χ5
doublema = movmean(M,3);


plot(t,doublema);
title('Διπλός ΚΜΟ 5χ3');
xlabel('Μήνας');
ylabel('Αφίξεις');

# Κεντρικός ΚΜΟ 2χ4
MA4 = movmean(Y,4);
CMA = movmean(MA4,2);
plot(t,CMA);
title('Κεντρικός ΚΜΟ 2χ4');
xlabel('Μήνας');
ylabel('Αφίξεις');

#Βήμα 2 Αποσύνθεσης
Step2 = Y./CMA;

#Βήμα 3 Αποσύνθεσης
Step3 = mean(Step2);

#Βήμα 4 Αποσύνθεσης - Αποεποχικοποιημένη Σειρά
Step4 = Y./Step3;

#Βήμα 5 Αποσύνθεσης - Αφαίρεση τυχαιότητας
MA3 = movmean(Step4,3);
Step5 = movmean(MA3,3);

#Βήμα 6 Αποσύνθεσης

slope = polyfit(t,Step5,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't speak Greek, so I'll assume that by two "equations" you actually mean two "values", which is what [`polyfit`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/polyfit.html) should give you if you pass it the argument `1`. You're fitting a polynomial of degree 1, i.e. an equation of the form `y = ax + b`, where you fit both `a` and `b`. To reconstruct your line then you use `y = slope(0)*t + slope(1)`, where `slope(0)` is your "slope" and `slope(0)` your "intercept" (or `y = slope(1)*t + slope(0)`, the docs don't state whether the coefficients are stored with increasing or decreasing degree.)

Comment: Yeah sorry for the literal Greek, I didn't change them because they basically serve only the purpose of being "titles" as comments etc. I get slope =
  -3.9606e+03   3.9419e+05

Shouldn't I only get the positive value ? Thanks for the answer by the way

Comment: Okay, It seems to work (?) using what you gave me but with slope 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1 cause it gave me an error. I'm 100% sure I've got everything wrong in the exercise but I'm going to close the question since you provided the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @DimitriosKarageorgos No, slope values shouldn't be positive by definition. Consider `polyfit(1:10, (-1:10),1)`. This is the equation for `y=-x`. You'll get `[0 -1]` (or `[-1 0]`, depending on the Octave convention, which you can btw check with this). All `polyfit` does is literally fit a straight line through your data and return the coefficients for that. If you think you should be getting different values, either your input is different from what you thought, you should not fit a straight line or something else entirely is going on.

Comment: A simple `scatter(t, Step5)` would plot your data points; add your line to the plot to verify that it is indeed the least-squares best fitting straight line through that point cloud.